write permissions for group
On a samba share on Linux, I want to have a directory that can be written to by different users (members of a group called 'users'). Subdirectories those users create also have to be writeable by every user in group 'users'.
As a member of 'users' I make the directory and set the group, permissions, the setgid bit and the ACL:
mkdir testdirectory
chgrp users testdirectory
chmod 775 testdirectory
chmod g+s testdirectory
setfacl -d -m g::rwx testdirectory

The permissions of the directory are now drwxrwsr-x+, the group is 'users'.
Result of getfacl testdirectory:
# owner: me
# group: users
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x

Test:
Another member of group 'users' connects via SMB, and creates a file in 'testdirectory'.
The file's permissions are -rwxr--r--, the group is 'users'.
Other group members are not allowed to change it.
A directory created by the same user in 'testdirectory' gets the permissions drwxr-sr-x+, group is 'users', and again other group members are not allowed to write to it.
I would have expected that every file and subdirectory inherits the permissions of 'testdirectory', but obviously I'm missing something.
How can I achieve the expected result?

I'm unfamiliar with Samba / ACL interactions, but quickly looking at man smb.conf suggests you need at least inherit acls = yes set in your share's options for ACL permissions to be honored.

In fact it makes a difference if that user is logged in locally on the system. So without using samba, the tests from above give the following result:
the permissions of a newly created file are still -rwxr--r-- (not good).  The directory gets the expected permissions: drwxrwsr-x+ (good)

Something is not adding up, a newly created file should get -rw-rw-r-- according to your ACL permissions. I wouldn't even know how a newly created file could acquire x by default for the owner, neither through umask nor through ACL permissions. Can you test in another directory? Maybe just run the first snippet you posted (the one you used to create the directory in the first place) in your home directory, then mkdir foo; touch bar inside the directory.

I did as you suggested, and everything works as expected. For the other user (even when loged in locally) it only works from cli, but not from the gnome desktop session: same permissions as before - -rwxr--r-- My problem now is how to make it work from gnome desktop.
